# Using Angular 6 how can we capture a particular div or component of page?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, angular6

I'm trying to achieve some functionality like when the user wants to download a part of the HTML page in an image or PDF format, not like a snipping tool but when he clicks download as a presentation (while an action is provided for that component).
He should that components content as an image or PDF. I don't see any modules already available.
Can someone guide me how to achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jspdf which will generate pdf based on DOM element present in the view.

```
npm install jspdf --save
```

import the jspdf.js library file into script section in angular.json

```
"scripts": [ "../node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js" ]
```

**Component:**

```
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf'

downloadPdf() {
    let doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.addHTML(document.getElementById("obrz"), function() {
       doc.save("obrz.pdf");
    });
}
```

Comment: It worked but few child components are getting missed in the generated PDF

Comment: It supports only HTML Elements which is embedded in the View. console.log(htmlcontent). You may need to access child component using viewChild and get the DOM Content and append it if required. Refer jsPDF Documentation https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/. Please upvote it.

Comment: Thanks, mate and Accepted, don't have enough reputation for my vote to be considered.